# How to only update one lib of podfile in cocoapods?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

In my `podfile`:

```
 platform:ios,'8.0'
 target "agriculturalApp" do

    pod 'IQKeyboardManager', '~>  3.3.7'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8.1'   #3.8.0才支持ipv6
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~>3.1.0'

    pod 'UILabel+Copyable'

    use_frameworks!
    pod 'ReactiveCocoa','~>4.1.0'

    pod 'EBForeNotification', '~> 1.0.6'

    post_install do |installer|
        installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'  ## or '3.0'
            end
        end
    end 
   
end
```

I have so many `pods` lib in my `podfile`, but how can I only update the custom `lib`?

Such as, you know, if I update `cocoapods`, I will update all of the `libs` in podfile. I just want to update `SDWebImage` to `~> 4.0.0-beta2`.

Comment: Fix version of all others pod, and it should work

Comment: @CZ54 Only this way? is there other method to do this?

Comment: pod update SDWebImage

Comment: @Mr.Bista I using `pod updateSDWebImage`, but it takes a very long time in `Performing a deep fetch of the `master` specs repo to improve future performance` , so I canceled it .

Comment: pod update SDWebImage --verbose, I waited for long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pod update [PODNAME]` as per the [docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html).

So, change the version (or remove if you want the newest version) for `SDWebImage` and run:

```
pod update SDWebImage
```